# Como obter PATH_INFO em Nginx quando usamos rewrite (url amigavel)?

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, nginx, url-rewrite

Eu criei um `.htaccess` na pasta `/var/www/project/`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond $1 !^(statics/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)|index\.php)$ #ignora a pasta /statics
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L] #Adiciona PATH_INFO
</IfModule>

<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
echo 'Path: ', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
```

Quando acesso `http://localhost/project/profile`, o index.php retorna isto:

```
Path: /profile
```

O problema é tentar fazer isto no Nginx. Eu tentei isto:

```
location ~ ^/project/(?!index\.php|statics/|data/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)$ {
    rewrite  ^(/project/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)$  $1/index.php/$2 break;
    return 500;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

    #if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
    #    return 404;
    #}

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Mas quando abro `http://localhost:8000/project/profile` ele mostra *404 Not Found*.

Como posso fazer o nginx funcionar como o .htaccess?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61160/3635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que funcione é necessário usar `last` no `rewrite` e `fastcgi_split_path_info` para configurar o `PATH_INFO`, exemplo:

> *Nota:* Use o caminho completo no rewrite e no location

```
location ~ ^/project/(?!index\.php/.*|index\.php$|statics/.*|data/.*)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)$ {
    rewrite ^/project/(?!index\.php/.*|statics/.*|data/.*)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/.]+)$ /project/index.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/project/(?!index\.php).*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    # Configura PATH_INFO
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```