# Como pegar o status HTTP correto?

Tags: php, nginx, redirecionamento, http-status

Eu tentei pegar o "status" de erro assim:

```
error_page 403 /error.php;
error_page 404 /error.php;
```

Mas `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']` retornar `200`, já no Apache ele retornar `404` (o resultado esperado).

Como definir as variáveis `$_SERVER[REDIRECT_STATUS]`, `$_SERVER[REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD]` e `$_SERVER[REDIRECT_URL]` usando o Nginix?

Comment: Desculpem, apaguei a resposta, pois ela era de outra pergunta.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: @LeandroCurioso Mas como faço para detectar o redirecionamento?

Comment: Corrija "retonar".

Comment: @Guill nas comunidades do SE você pode editar postagens do outros usuários quando encontrar erros gramaticais.

Comment: Achei muito pouco pra editar. Alguns usuários não concordam com alguém editar seus posts por erros pequenos. Mas é uma questão de interpretação. Emfim, correções aplicadas e é o que importa.

Comment: Então @Guill qualquer edição que favoreça as comunidades SE são bem-vindas e se um dia você editar alguma de boa fé e mesmo assim o autor original não gostar, recomendo você mostrar este link: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3749/3635 Uma boa tarde xará (acredito que se chame Guilherme Também)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após uma breve pesquisa, encontrei isto [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info/forum/nginx:_404_plugin_not_working/#comment-d9a044ed6f21e3386323866defde2788), existem algumas melhorias que podem ser feitas, mas a ideia é que o `location` falso resolve o problema, com o tempo irei melhorar o código ou adicionar um novo exemplo.

Exemplo básico:

```
# Configura um local "falso" para
error_page 404 @fakeroute404;

# Acessa o local falso
location @fakeroute404 {
    ...# Outros dados

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params; #inclui os parametros fastcgi

    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD "GET"; # Configura o metodo
    fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 404;  # Configura o estado
    fastcgi_param REDIRECT_URL $uri;    # Configura a URL
}
```